# ibus-m17n input method no longer works on libreoffice-still

Tags: arch-linux, libreoffice, ibus

I've noticed it on the Desktop on which I installed Arch linux yesterday. It used to work on the laptop until I ran `pacman -Syu` today! As far as I've seen, it never worked on libreoffice-fresh, calligra and wps!

It still works with firefox, atom, vscode on both the laptop and desktop, how to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already seen this, but in case not here's a bit from the Arch Linux wiki on IBus troubleshooting with respect to LibreOffice... https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#LibreOffice

Comment: @DavidYockey, I never had to add those in `.bashrc` before! Thanks, it now works on both libreoffice-still and calligra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never had to add those `export ...` lines in `.bashrc` over the past 2+ months on linux. For libreoffice-still, I've to add these two lines:

```
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

in `~/.bashrc` and for calligra, I've to add all three of these:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

in `~/.bashrc` on KDE Plasma Desktop.